# Is there a way to read DjVu files on a 4th gen Kindle?

Tags: kindle, djvu, 4th-generation-kindle

[DJVU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu) format is a very good format both in terms of file size an readability.

Is there a way that I can read DjVu files on a [4th generation Kindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle#Fourth_generation)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no out of the box possibility.

The easiest way would be to convert the file to pdf, of course this would make the DjVu advantages disappear.

The alternative is to modify your Kindle by installing a compatible reader. One possibility that is still actively developed is [Librerator](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=198742) (which is also a superior for viewing larger pdfs). You will however have to jailbreak your Kindle and install [KUAL](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=203326), which will possibly void warranty.

Comment: and which approach do you usually prefer?

Answer (score 3):

What I always do to read DjVu ebooks on my Kindle is the following (In case they do not contain important images).

1. I convert them to plain text using: https://www.djvu-pdf.com/ - just choose the convert to plain text option after uploading your file
2. I open the text file with my Kindle.

Like that you have the freedom to adapt font size etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Duokan](http://www.duokan.com/). It is available for Kindle 2, 3, 4, 5 and DX versions.

It's upgrade and it's safe.

The extension allows Kindle to work with EPUB, CHM, DOC, TXT, ZIP, RAR, JPG, PNG, BMP and **DJVU** formats.

Supports fonts in **ttf** format.

Allows smart display PDF pages: [Classic view](http://www.ebooky.cz/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/duokan-amazon-kindle-cz-04.bmp) | [Smart view](http://www.ebooky.cz/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/duokan-amazon-kindle-cz-01.bmp)

Installation files:
[K3](http://balkanskypoloostrov.cz/duokancestina/k3.zip) | 
[Kindle 4 contactless](http://balkanskypoloostrov.cz/duokancestina/k4-k5.zip) | 
[Kindle 4 Black (so-called K5)](http://balkanskypoloostrov.cz/duokancestina/k4-k5.zip) | 
[Kindle Touch](http://balkanskypoloostrov.cz/duokancestina/kt-kp.zip) | 
[Kindle Paperwhite](http://balkanskypoloostrov.cz/duokancestina/kt-kp.zip)

Installation procedure in Czech (use google translator):
[For new Kindle](http://duokan-cesky.blogspot.com/2014/01/instalace-alternativniho-software.html) (4, 5) | 
[For old Kindle](https://www.chip.cz/novinky/tipy-triky/cteni-dokumentu-formatu-epub-chm-doc-a-djvu/) (2, 3, DX)

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it with using **DjVuLibre**
If you install the `djvulibre-bin` (Ubuntu install link) package, you will now have the `djvups` command, which converts a **DejaVu** file to PostScript `.ps`. You can then use any tool (like `ps2pdf`) to turn that `.ps` into a `.pdf`.

Full command sequence

```
djvups original_file.djvu temp.ps
ps2pdf temp.ps outputfile.pdf
rm temp.ps
```

In my experience using `djvups` is much faster than using ImageMagick's convert, and uses much, much less memory.
The conversion to `.ps` quick, but the conversion to pdf step can take longer.
The pdf (and ps file) ***is much larger*** than the .djvu file (about 100 times the size)

Finally, you can use PDF file or convert it to `mobi` or `ePub`.

[Here is](https://www.technomancy.org/kindle/djvu/) more detailed information.

Another solution is to use [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) and after installation:

Add book -> right click on it -> select `Convert` -> `Convert individually`.